# Prevent/detect cloud location in FileSavePicker in UWP apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, uwp

The `FileSavePicker` on the Universal Windows Platform enables users to select cloud locations like OneDrive. I have an app that contains sensitive data which should not be saved to cloud locations.

Is there a way to prevent locations except for the local storage and SD cards to show up in the picker?

Alternatively, can I detect such a location being selected for issuing a warning at least?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you an answer for the second part:

> Alternatively, can I detect such a location being selected for issuing
>   a warning at least?

Yes, for this you can use the `StorageFolder.Provider` property. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.provider) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storageprovider).

For example the `Provider.Id` of OneDrive is “OneDrive”… so with a check for that you immediately know that the folder is a OneDrive folder. Maybe a check for id=”computer” is a good idea... if it's "computer" then no waring is needed, otherwise just show the warning...

And another hint: Provider can be null (which is traditionally not a local folder), so a check for that is also a good idea.

For the first part:

I don’t know about a solution to filter out folders from the `FileSavePicker`. I don’t think this is possible. If you want to have control on this maybe the [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) would be the way to go. 
(I don’t know your exact situation, but [KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx) is maybe relevant..)